# How to set a topic permission for a user on a remote server using the rabbitmq CLI Tools

Tags: rabbitmq, kubernetes-helm, bitnami, rabbitmqadmin

is there a way to create a topic permission for a user with the cli tool rabbitmqadmin on a remote system?

Using the Bitnami Helm Chart https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/rabbitmq

Will use it for scripting so the Web UI is not an option
Found there is Method for the other CLI Tool rabbitmqctl can not connect via rabbitmqctl to my cluster even I have a kubernetes Service + Portforwarding for port 4369

I already created a User + host permissions via rabbitmqadmin
So the rabbitmqadmin cli tool itself is working in general

```
rabbitmqadmin --help
```

gives me the following methods

```
Object Manipulation
===================

  declare exchange name=... type=... [auto_delete=... durable=... internal=... arguments=...]
  declare queue name=... [auto_delete=... durable=... arguments=... node=... queue_type=...]
  declare binding source=... destination=... [destination_type=... routing_key=... arguments=...]
  declare vhost name=... [tracing=...]
  declare user name=... password=... OR password_hash=... tags=... [hashing_algorithm=...]
  declare permission vhost=... user=... configure=... write=... read=...
  declare parameter component=... name=... value=...
  declare policy name=... pattern=... definition=... [priority=... apply-to=...]
  declare operator_policy name=... pattern=... definition=... [priority=... apply-to=...]
  declare vhost_limit vhost=... name=... value=...
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to use the command **rabbitmqctl**

```
rabbitmqctl set_topic_permissions -p my-vhost janeway amq.topic "^janeway-.*" "^janeway-.*"
```

Reference document : https://www.rabbitmq.com/rabbitmqctl.8.html#set_topic_permissions

if you can't connect using **rabbitmqctl**, you can try `exec` inside the POD of RabbitMQ manually.

`kubectl exec -it <Rabbitmq-1 or POD name> -- /bin/bash` inside it you can access the **rabbitmqctl**

Comment: THX! "kubectl exec -it" is a good idea. Even useful for scripting like "kubectl exec -it <Rabbitmq-1 or POD name> -- rabbitmqctl set_topic_permissions ....." will work for the beginning